# Increasing visibility to questions by upvoting comments = cheating?

Tags: bug, questions, comment

I have begun posting questions in CrossValidated and recognized that many go almost unnoticed.

I realized that by periodically upvoting the corresponding comments the question may reappear as active, thus ending up to be more visible and for more times.

I guess this is however tantamount to cheating, and it's worth knowing as a limitation of the system. Or not?

Comment: Are you sure that was the reason your question was bumped? Not edits to the question?

Comment: I... don't think upvoting comments bumps the question. I don't think I ever saw that happening. Either it was edited, as @Scortchi suggested, or maybe the community user bumped your questions, as it does to random (not entirely, but not worth going into specifics) questions every once in a while?

Comment: In any case, see [Is there a polite /accepted way of “bumping” up questions?](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/735/17230).